# How to make a viewController always remain in Portrait mode , iOS?

Tags: ios, navigation, rotation

I have a mainController that can rotate to portrait and landscape mode. I have some buttons on screen that can navigate me to other controllers. The thing is that i want my mainController to rotate but the other controllers ALWAYS to stay in portrait mode.
The problem is that when i rotate my mainController to landscape and i navigate to another controller , while on landscape mode , the other controller comes in landscape mode too!
How can i prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

override shoudlAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method in each viewController that should remain in portrait.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

In iOS 6, there are new methods. But iOS 6 is still under NDA, so you can see changes on developer.apple.com if you have a developer account.

Comment: No it doesnt work! its not so simple! If i go to this controller ok with this code u cant rotate. But if i rotate on the previous controller on landscape mode and then go to this controller , while i am in landscape mode, then the controller rotates to landscape too1

Comment: the second controller is pushed on a UINavigationController ? The problem is maybe here, if you have a viewController in landscape it's  odd to push a new in portrait only. Try to present it modally.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Implement this in the view controllers that you want to be portrait only

Comment: No it doesnt work! its not so simple! If i go to this controller ok with this code u cant rotate. But if i rotate on the previous controller on landscape mode and then go to this controller , while i am in landscape mode, then the controller rotates to landscape too1